# Fixing title in rxvt application

Tags: rxvt

I need to use the title (-title/-T) for a terminal app called cmus in rxvt. But, When I am running

```
urxvt -e cmus -T "cmus"
```

It opens and closes. cmus is a music player and it changes the title dynamically depending on the track so I'm finding it hard to bind some key to bring it forward. Is there any other way to affix it's title?

Comment: Does https://superuser.com/questions/308650/keep-cmus-from-changing-terminal-title help?  Basically stop the app from changing the title.

Comment: Yes, you should configure `cmus` to stop changing the title. There's no way to disable the `\e]2;title\a` escape in `rxvt` (or to selectively disable terminal escapes, except for those considered "insecure", which the `set_title` apparently is not).

Comment: The ```:set set_term_title=false``` can do this, is there any configrc file for cmus where I can put this in?

Comment: I found the rc file's location in the man pages. It is located here ~/.config/cmus/rc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rc` file for `cmus` is located at `~/.config/cmus/rc`. If it is not there create one. In there put

```
fset set_term_title=false
```

This will stop `cmus` from changing the title dynamically.